# Autostart program in Safe Mode

Tags: windows, boot, safe-mode

I'm wondering if there's a way to autostart programs in Safe Mode. I know, generally it ignores autostart entries in SM, but still I'd appreciate any advice. The program is a GUI application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there's a way to make that. First, you can enable certain services in safe mode, they would launch required applications. Second, shell customization works in Safe Mode, so you can replace explorer with your own application.

Comment: A nagging voice in my head keeps telling me that you are doing insanely weird things here ...

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to do so. One of the easiest way to do this is adding your app in Windows registry.

> Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Here you will find a String value with default value data

> Shell = explorer.exe

Now you can add your app here by editing its value data, so that after edit it will look like

> Shell = explorer.exe,app1,app2

This will make these apps to run in safe mode.

Warning: Do not remove explorer.exe . Doing this will prevent auto start of Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

If there were a way, this would kinda defeat the purpose of Safe Mode. After all, it's meant as a last-resort option if the OS is in a state where nothing else would work anymore. It's perfectly sensible to *not* automatically start anything that might tear the system down then. And perfectly sensible as well to not even include an option to do so – because, if there were, then all programs and their dogs would be so important they'd need to run in Safe Mode too ... and I think you can tell where that leads, then.

Comment: Needless to say, if you regularly work in safe more that you apparently would enjoy the niceties of a program running automatically, then I think you have other problems to solve first.